# Animate listview rows, what is the proper place to do this?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-navigation

I am trying to animate the rows of a Nav drawer:

I want the icon to rotate 30 degrees and I want the whole row to slide in from left.

So while the row is sliding, the image should rotate 30 degrees and slide too.

I have the following method to do this:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            
            
            
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        
        
        animTranslate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.con,
                R.anim.rotate_nav_drawer);
        txtTitle.setTypeface(tf); 
        txtTitle.setTextSize(18);

        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.con, R.anim.rotatenav);
        
        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());    
        
        imgIcon.startAnimation(rotation);
        imgIcon.startAnimation(animTranslate);
        txtTitle.setAnimation(animTranslate);
        
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        // displaying count
        // check whether it set visible or not
        if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
            txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        }else{
            // hide the counter view
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Problems:

The image does not rotate but slides in.
The animation happens only once, that is when the nav drawer is opened for the first time.

What do I miss here?

Here are my animations xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="900"
        android:fromXDelta="30%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" >
    </translate>

</set>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="30" />
```

Although I can call these animations on navDrawerOpen, but I am clueless as to how to reference the individual views there.

#### Edit:

Here is my complete adapter:

```
public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    String fontPath = "fonts/HelveticaNeue-Light.otf";
    Typeface tf; 


    Animation animTranslate;
    
    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontPath);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            
            
            
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        
        
        animTranslate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.con,
                R.anim.rotate_nav_drawer);
        txtTitle.setTypeface(tf); 
        txtTitle.setTextSize(18);

        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.con, R.anim.rotatenav);
        
        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());    
        
    //  imgIcon.startAnimation(rotation);
    //  imgIcon.startAnimation(animTranslate);
    //  txtTitle.setAnimation(animTranslate);
        
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        // displaying count
        // check whether it set visible or not
        if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
            txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        }else{
            // hide the counter view
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Plz show your full adapter.

Comment: Updated the question, please check!

Comment: you have to give the bounty or it will expire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use interpolator and make a few changes to your xml.
Also, as stated by Bruce add the translateAnimation to rotate_nav_drawer_image.xml.
The xml:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 <!--- android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
       If you add this intepolator here remove it from translate and rotate-->
 android:fillAfter="true"
 >
<translate
    android:duration="900"
    android:fromXDelta="30%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
      />
<rotate
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="30"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatMode="reverse" <!-- "reverse" to have the animation reverse direction with each iteration or "repeat" to have the animation loop from the beginning each time. -->
    android:repeatCount="-1"  <!-- can also use "infinite" -->
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"    <!--You can exeriment with linear_interpolator... -->
          />
```

Add it to your imageView

```
animTranslateRotImage = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(myContext,
            R.anim.rotate_nav_drawer_image);
imgIcon.startAnimation(animTranslateRotImage);
```

If the animation shows only first time the navigation Drawer is opened. Call `invalidateViews()` on your drawer listView to force it to be redrawn. Like

```
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
mDrawerList.setAdater( //.....
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {


        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // Force it to be redrawn.
            mDrawerList.invalidateViews();

            /* If this did not work call
               use mDrawerList.refreshDrawableState() or
               mDrawerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            */


            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hio mate, I did grab something from your answer - tr refresh my views. However I used a layout animation. which works well. I am waiting if I get more answers, cheers:)

Comment: so you are animating whole layout, which layout? Also do share your working answer I wanted to see and learn something from it... If you can edit my answer add the code to it or post in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work, but f the animation on txtTitle is working correctly, but not the one on imgIcon, maybe you could make the code of imgIcon work more like txtTitle. Change the icon's XML to be a set that combines the two:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="900"
        android:fromXDelta="30%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />
    <rotate
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:toDegrees="30" />
</set>
```

And then set the animation on the icon like you do with the title:

```
imgIcon.setAnimation(rotation);
txtTitle.setAnimation(animTranslate);
```